# Second testWidgets method call fails in group of Integration Test in Flutter, but succeeds when run in isolation

Tags: flutter, dart

**Scenario**

I have a simple Flutter app with 3 screens: `LoginPage`, `CheckoutPage` and `DashboardPage`. The `LoginPage` has two buttons: one for reaching the `CheckoutPage` (with `ValueKey('Subscribe')` and the other for reaching the `DashboardPage` (with `ValueKey('Login')`).

**Code**

My *integration_test/main_test.dart* looks as follows:

```
void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  group('end to end test', () {
    // setUp(() async {
    //   app.main();
    // });
    testWidgets(
        'Given textfields for Email and Password, When correct values are entered, Then user is taken to their DashboardPage',
        (tester) async {
      // Arrange
      app.main();

      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));

      // Act
      Finder emailTextField = find.byKey(const ValueKey('EmailAddress'));
      Finder passwordTextField = find.byKey(const ValueKey('Password'));
      Finder loginButton = find.byKey(const ValueKey('Login'));
      Finder dashboardPage = find.byType(DashboardPage);

      // Assert
      expect(emailTextField, findsOneWidget);
      expect(passwordTextField, findsOneWidget);
      expect(loginButton, findsOneWidget);

      await tester.enterText(emailTextField, 'ayan@qolarisdata.com');
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));

      await tester.enterText(passwordTextField, 'Test@123');
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4));

      await tester.tap(loginButton);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      expect(dashboardPage, findsOneWidget);
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    });
    testWidgets(
        'Given a Subscribe button, When the button is tapped on, Then the user is taken to Checkout screen',
        (tester) async {
      app.main();
      // await tester.pumpWidget(const app.MainApp());

      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));

      expect(find.byKey(const ValueKey('Subscribe')), findsOneWidget);
      await tester.tap(find.byKey(const ValueKey('Subscribe')));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      expect(find.byType(CheckoutPage), findsOneWidget);
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    });
  });
}
```

**Problem**

When I run the test at group level, the first test runs successfully and then the second test fails with the following error: **The following TestFailure was thrown running a test:
Expected: exactly one matching candidate
Actual: _KeyWidgetFinder:<Found 0 widgets with key [<'Subscribe'>]: []>**

However, when I run only this second test, it passes.

I suspect that in a group, once the first test completes, the app is taken to the `DashboardPage`. When the second test starts, the app probably doesn't start from the `LoginPage` again.

I have tried commenting out `app.main()` and placing `await tester.pumpWidget(const app.MainApp());` or

```
await tester.pumpWidget(
      MaterialApp.router(
        routerConfig: GoRouteInformation.router,
      ),
    );
```

but keep getting the same error.

**Request**

I would like to know what is causing the second test to fail when run in a group and what changes I need to make to rectify my code to enable both tests to pass while run in a group.

Answer (score 0):

In your first test, your are login and reaching to dashboard page ,
While in second test , you expecting the login screen but actually dashboard page displayed because app state from first test remains the same for second test.
To achieve clean state between tests, you need to logout post first test execution.

How to achieve clean state between tests, there are two ways:

1. Logout in the last of the first test.

or

2. add teardown

   ```
   group('tests', () {
   tearDown(() async {
     //Logout logic
     cleanLoggedInUserState();
   });

   testWidgets(
       'Test 1',
           (WidgetTester tester) async {
         //your test code
   });

   testWidgets(
       'Test 2',
           (WidgetTester tester) async {
         //your test code
   });
   });
   ```